# GDI Animation C++ not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, animation, gdi

I'm trying to animate some squares, using a class for these objects. when the `MoveSquare` method is called, the squares only move one step, then they stop.

When I try to use a value returned by `rand()%50` instead of `STEP`, then the squares move.

So can someone tell me what the problem is? Why are they not moving each time the `WM_TIMER` message is received. Here is my code:

```
#include "Square.h"
#define STEP 10

void Square::DrawSquare(HDC hdc,int rx,int ry, int lx, int ly) {

    Rectangle(hdc,x+rx,y+ry,x+lx,y+ly);
}


void Square::MoveSquare(HWND hwnd_ ,int mod_x_Size,int mod_y_Size) {

       x=x+STEP;
       y=y+STEP;

       InvalidateRect(hwnd_,NULL,TRUE);
}


Square::Square(void) {

    x=0;
    y=0; 
}

Square::~Square(void) {

}
```

Function where i receive and response to system messages

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdc;

    Square square[NUMARUL_DE_FIGURI];

       HBRUSH shapeColor;

    switch (msg) {


case WM_SIZE :       
        mod_x_Size = LOWORD (lparam) ;
        mod_y_Size = HIWORD (lparam) ;
        break ;

case WM_TIMER:

     for (int i=0;i<NUMARUL_DE_FIGURI;i++) {
            square[i].MoveSquare(hwnd,mod_x_Size,mod_y_Size);
     }

case WM_PAINT: 

    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

   for (int i=0;i<NUMARUL_DE_FIGURI;i++) {

        shapeColor = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255)));

        square[i].DrawSquare(hdc,(mod_x_Size/2)-((i*60)+60),(mod_y_Size/2)-((i*60)+60),(mod_x_Size/2)-((i*60)+120),(mod_y_Size/2)-((i*60)+120)); 
    }

    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
       KillTimer(hwnd,1);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i set timer in main function

Comment: How, where and when do you call `MoveSquare` and `DrawSquare`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Call `InvalideRect` and `UpdateWindow` in `WM_TIMER` event. Add a `break;` at the end of the `WM_TIMER` event. Going into handler of `WM_PAINT` without a real `WM_PAINT` message would have not effect.
2. In handler of `WM_PAINT`, use the `HDC` returned by `BeginPaint`. Do **not** call `GetDC` when handling `WM_PAINT`.

EDIT -
Your `square` is a local variable to `WndProc`, and it will be initialized to `(0,0)` every time `WndProc` is called. You can change it to `static`.

Try and see if it can solve the problem.

Comment: did not help . in this case , squares did not move even one time , as was in my case

Comment: `square` will get initialized every time `WndProc` is called, so every time it is in the same position.

Comment: First, I wonder why you cannot use static vars. I don't quite understand your two variable approach, how should it work if the two variables are not global or static? If you want to keep the value of `square` when the `WndProc` returns, it must be kept somewhere outside the function (or in static local vars).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "square" to be repainted at every WM_TIMER event, then it's not enough to just call `InvalidateRect`, as that will just mark an area as needed to be repainted. Call [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to force a new WM_PAINT event.

Comment: i call UpdateWindow after call CreateWindow and ShowWindow, but anyway with no result

Comment: @develoops You have to do it in WM_TIMER (or `MoveSquare`) too, to force the WM_PAINT event to be sent.

Comment: same result. tried to do it in WM_TIMER and then in MoveSquare, but with no success